# HighStocks Array Series

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

Im creating a singleline series chart using dates and closing prices from yahoo. I have converted the dates into JS timestamps and put them in an array named timeStampArray and put the closing prices into an array named closePrices.

I can populate the chart with data like so:

```
data : [
          [ 1361750400000, 442.80],
          [ 1361491200000, 450.81]

       ],
```

I wish to use the data from my arrays and the API says to use an array with two values for x and y, like this

`data: [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]]`

therefore can I combine my two arrays so that they fit this format?

I can only find examples of how to combine my arrays into key-value pairs like this `{'test1':'1', 'test2':'2'};`

Also when I create the chart using hardcoded data it orders the dates in ascending order but I want it to keep the ordering that they are input, e.g 25th Feb before 22nd Feb as this is showing historical data.

Is there a way to correct this?

Heres the jsFiddle of my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/mXnZy/

**update:** ive tried

```
var timeClose = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<data.query.results.quote.length; i++)
            {
                   timeClose.push( [timeStampArray[i], closePrices[i]] );
            }
```

however this outputs `[1361750400000, 442.80, 1361491200000, 450.81]` which is wrong.

Comment: in regard to your update - no matter what order your array values are in, the chart is still going to plot them on the correct x value...they won't appear out of x order, nor should they...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want them sorted in reverse order, you can use the 'reversed' property on the x axis:

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.reversed

If you mean that you want them listed in whatever order they're entered, without being sorted, it will be much more complicated.

You could provide ordinal x values, and provide the date as additional data.  You could then use the axis label formatter to show the dates that you wish.